# Laravel new not creating "app.blade.php"

Tags: php, laravel-5

Normally whenever I create a laravel project, the "app.blade.php" file would get created by default but for some reason its not happening anymore.

I tried both the "laravel new {project name}" way and the "composer create laravel/laravel {project name}" way and neither work.

Anyone know why this might be?

Comment: You can't find app.blade.php in resources/views/?

Comment: it might be a change in 5.1 which was released less than a week ago. A similar change I noticed was that `php artisan make:model` doesn't create a migration by default anymore.